# get digits using javascript RegExp, min 2 digits, sometimes 3 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I grab from a string a set number of digits?

For example:

```
The random number = 0.87934738749
```

All I need is 0.87 no rounding, just truncated.

The only caveat is that I want to do this using RegExp, I know how to do this using Math.pow with Math.floor and other methods, I am trying to better understand Regular Expressions.

So far I have been led to examples that are baffling, RegExp is not my thing, the length is a minimum of 2 digits but under certain circs, it needs to be 3 digits, thats what I forgot to add in my original post.

So trying :-

```
x = String(numb).match( new RegExp("/\d+(\.\d{1,"+p+"})?/") )[0];
```

an error `Cannot read property '0' of null` or a return of`null` if I take the [0] off the end.

Comment: what do you mean by "sometimes 3 digits"? What is the criteria for the three digits? Anyway, I would personally go for something as simple as that: `(?=(\d+\.\d{2,3}))` https://regex101.com/r/wB9fC6/1#javascript

Comment: What are you passing in as `numb` and `p` in the case that it returns `null`? Generally, we need inputs and expected outputs when you are asking us to debug something for you.

Comment: 0.87 or 0.879 the criteri is not important, what I want to understand is why new RegExp which is meant to make a regular expression, is not working.

Comment: numb is the number, p is the precision

Comment: `new RegExp("\\d+(\\.\\d{1,"+p+"})?")` should work. Double escaping and no regex delimiter

Comment: Not the meaning, the actual values. When debugging, you want to know, "if I input this, I get that". Please look at [mcve].

Comment: Thanks gents, thats working beautifully, I am still pondering why and hows of RegExp, but I am grateful to you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments above about the precision (the case of three digits), I think a correct answer can be this one:

```
var rndm = 0.87934738749;
var precision = 3;

x = String(rndm).match(new RegExp("(?=(\\d+\\.\\d{2,"+precision+"}))"));

alert(x);
```

Example with precision 4: https://jsfiddle.net/edz4crc8/

Note that x will contain the result (0.879 in the case above), the regex actually is:

```
(?=(\d+\.\d{2,number}))
```

- (?= asserts that the regex can be matched
- \d+ matches one to unlimited digits ([0-9])
- . matches literally `.` (also, you may add a comma rule if needed)
- \d{2,number} matches any digit between two and **number** times, where number is the precision given by the variable precision in the case above.

Your error probably was mostly about the escaping the regex itself but, in any case, in my opinion, it is better to use an assertion for such a case.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it would be more straightforward to implement using [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var r = 0.8793...
var prec = 3
r.toFixed(prec) // => "0.879"
```

Note, though, that it is not identical to what a regex would do since it involves rounding. For instance:

```
var r = 0.8796...
r.toFixed(prec) // => "0.880"
```

EDIT: Ok, misread the part where it says you *don't* want to round. Disregard. I'm leaving this here in case someone wants rounding.